# Wanted to iterate through column Rating(outof10) and replace those values having "na" with np.NaN

Tags: pandas

[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3HqO.png)

i tried iterating through values in the column ratingoutof10 to replace all na values with np.NaN please review my code, why am i getting this error and what is correct code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace your code with this and it will work just fine

```
df['Rating(outof10)'] = df['Rating(outof10)'].apply(lambda x  : x.replace('na', np.nan))
```

Comment: thanks:) ArchaAngelPwn but i want to know that what is lambda here?? what does it do?

Comment: Lambda is an anonymous function for python. Essentially it is like a 1 line function written this was so you don’t have to write a traditional could of lines for a function. It’s not as fast, and not as good for huge projects but it’s good for shorthand projects and if your doing something that isn’t very expensive (like this replace). SO isn’t the best for “how to” so if your not curious about lambda and want to learn more I highly suggest you research it to help utilize it to its full potential